# Airflow/SQLAlchemy Error - Loading context has changed within a load/refresh handler

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, airflow

I am attempting to use clairvoyant's [db-cleanup dag](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/db-cleanup) to clear metadata in our xcom table, but when I run it, I receive the following warning, printed thousands of times before I manually stop the job in order to not take down our mysql instance:

```
SAWarning: Loading context for <BaseXCom at 0x7f26f789b370> has changed within a load/refresh handler, suggesting a row refresh operation took place. If this event handler is expected to be emitting row refresh operations within an existing load or refresh operation, set restore_load_context=True when establishing the listener to ensure the context remains unchanged when the event handler completes.
```

The other cleanup tasks work fine, but it is the xcom table in particular I am having trouble with. We have hundreds/thousands of active dags and so the xcom table is constantly being written to nearly every second or two. I think that is what is causing this error, the fact that the data is continually changing while it is being queried.

I have been unable to find the cause of this or any examples of how this can be resolved. I tried adding a `"restore_load_context":True`  line as per [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html) but it did not work.

Here are the snippets I attempted to add to the database object and the cleanup task:

```
    {
    "airflow_db_model": XCom,
    "age_check_column": XCom.execution_date,
    "keep_last": False,
    "keep_last_filters": None,
    "keep_last_group_by": None,
    "restore_load_context":True
},
```

....

```
def cleanup_function(**context):

logging.info("Retrieving max_execution_date from XCom")
max_date = context["ti"].xcom_pull(
    task_ids=print_configuration.task_id, key="max_date"
)
max_date = dateutil.parser.parse(max_date)  # stored as iso8601 str in xcom

airflow_db_model = context["params"].get("airflow_db_model")
state = context["params"].get("state")
age_check_column = context["params"].get("age_check_column")
keep_last = context["params"].get("keep_last")
keep_last_filters = context["params"].get("keep_last_filters")
keep_last_group_by = context["params"].get("keep_last_group_by")
restore_load_context = context["params"].get("restore_load_context")
```

In order to not paste too much code here, I am using the same code in the [db-cleanup dag](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/tree/master/db-cleanup). Has anyone encountered this and found a way to resolve?

I am very inexperienced with sqlalchemy and am entirely unsure where else to place this code or how to go about it.

Comment: Hello fellow Airflow user! :D
I am using also the same code.
Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @PhilippeHebert I never was able to resolve this, but a built-in cleanup function was just added in 2.3.0: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20838
Otherwise I built a DAG that did a similar job to delete rows based on age but used regular SQL Operators  instead of sqlalchemy

Comment: Wow that's very nice! Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I'll definitely be looking forward to use a provider-supported alternative.